# How to make ChangeableText transparent in andengine

Tags: android, text, transparent, andengine

I'm using AndEngine in my Android application. I have to display a message. So I used ChangeableText as follows:

```
   ChangeableText text;
    text = new ChangeableText(100, y , mFont, "My message");
    text.setAlpha(0);
    resourceManager.getScene().attachChild(text);
    texts.add(text);
```

As you see, the text should be transparent and not visible to user at first, but it's not. Would you please help me find out what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution to this is explained here

http://www.andengine.org/forums/post16082.html?hilit=setAlpha#p16082

Basically, be sure your font is WHITE where you declare mFont and you can then use setAlpha or the setColor method of the setColor(int red, int green, int blue, int alpha) variety.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's solved. Again thanks.  text.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);